# Why the fields of the quasi-TEM mode of microstrip line tend to concentrate in the dielectric as frequency goes higher?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, dispersion, microwaves, waveguide

A microstrip line is a waveguiding structure as shown below:
[image]

Because of the inhomogeneity, the fundamental mode of propagation is a quasi-TEM mode, which means that the z components of the E and H fields are much smaller than the transverse components, but nonzero. In the limit $freq \rightarrow 0$, both $E_z$ and $H_z$ tend to zero.

We know that the field pattern (on the transverse plane) of an "exact" TEM mode is independent of frequency. However, it is not the case for quasi-TEM modes. It is observed that the effective dielectric constant of microstrip is an increasing function of frequency, for example

[image]
(figure taken from R. E. Collins, *Foundations for Microwave Engineering*. For the case of this figure, the relative permittivity of the dielectric material is 2.26)

We assume that the dielectric material itself does not have significant dispersion in the frequency range of interest, so that this result is solely due to the behavior of the quasi-TEM mode. The increasing effective dielectric constant indicates that the electromagnetic fields tend to concentrate in the dielectric region as frequency goes higher. My question: is there an explanation for this field concentration behavior? Namely, why do high frequency fields like to stay in the dielectric more than in the air region?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: I don't have time to think about this hard enough to come up with a solid answer, but think about what happens in the limit $\lambda\to2H$.

Comment: @ThePhoton When $\lambda \rightarrow 2H$, other modes of propagation may occur, but how does that affect the behavior of the fundamental (quasi-TEM) mode?

Answer (score 0):

For the wave simultaneously to exist in the dielectric and in the air it must slow down in the latter so its propagating wavelength that is somewhere in between the two must get shorter than otherwise it would be in air and get longer in the dielectric.
As you increase the frequency more of the wave concentrates in the dielectric per unit length because you have more "waves" per unit length, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775936/coupled-microstrip-waveguide-why-do-the-even-and-odd-modes-have-different-wave/775966#775966) and also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/765147/why-cant-a-wave-in-the-cladding-of-a-waveguide-phase-match-to-a-guided-wave/767077#767077). Of course, this assumes radiation is negligible as the frequency increases.

Comment: I could not understand the meaning of "more waves per unit length". Can you quantify what you said? The two posts you cited do not seem to be related to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Wave in air: $\lambda_0=c/\nu$;  wave in dielectric: $\lambda_1 = \lambda _0/\sqrt{\epsilon_1}$; wave in the microstrip waveguide:$\lambda_g$ -  then $\lambda_1 <\lambda_g <\lambda_0$. Let $\nu \to \infty$, $\lambda_{0,1,g} \to 0$, and ignore radiation. When both $H \gg \lambda_g$  AND $W \gg \lambda_g$ then under the strip you can have a now "almost" TEM-like propagation having top/bottom PEC and left/right sides under strip PMC walls.

Comment: Yes, but that does not explain why more fields are concentrated in the dielectric, as frequency goes up.

Comment: Yes, it does explain it because you also have to have the phases be matched in the two media by the single propagating wave; this is why the referenced posts are relevant and are related to your question.